# Apply a function to a pandas column where that function does not accept NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I need to match street names to gps coordinates in a pandas dataframe. I use OSRM for this; I can give OSRM a list of GPS coordinates and it will give me the names, but my series contains NaNs and OSRM does not accept nulls or zeros, so I need to filter them out (easy) but then put the results back in the corresponding rows; how do I do this? Edit: there are other columns in the dataframe (symbolised by `t` here, but there are more) that I cannot lose.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import json

path = [
  51.954974, 5.857131,
  51.955014, 5.860725,
  np.nan, np.nan,
  51.954168, 5.866390,
  51.954889, 5.868611,
]
path = [ {'t': t, 'lat': c[0], 'lon': c[1]} for t, c in enumerate(zip(*[path[i::2] for i in range(2)]))]
df = pd.DataFrame(path)

path = ';'.join(list(df[pd.notnull(df.lat)].apply(lambda x: str(x.lon) + ',' + str(x.lat), axis=1)))
osrm = 'http://router.project-osrm.org' # currently down
#osrm = 'http://localhost:5000'
url = osrm + '/match/v1/car/' + path + '?overview=full&annotations=nodes&tidy=true'

# OSRM is down now but this return [ "Metamorfosenallee", "Burgemeester Matsersingel", "Burgemeester Matsersingel", "Batavierenweg" ]
matched = [tp['name'] for tp in requests.post(url).json()['tracepoints']]

# how do I now get
#  t lat        lon        name
#  0 51.954974, 5.857131,  Metamorfosenallee
#  1 51.955014, 5.860725,  Burgemeester Matsersingel
#  2 np.nan,    np.nan,    np.nan
#  3 51.954168, 5.866390,  Burgemeester Matsersingel
#  4 51.954889, 5.868611,  Batavierenweg
```

(edited to add extra column I do not want to lose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be many shorter ways to reach the goal. But you can try steps below.

First, separate rows containing `NaN` values and store it in `t`. I assume `NaN` can also happen only in either `lat` or `lon`. You can improve it.

```
t = df.loc[df.lat.isnull() | df.lon.isnull()]
t
    lat        lon        
2  NaN        NaN
```

Drop rows with `NaN` values from `df`

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df
    lat        lon        
0  51.954974  5.857131
1  51.955014  5.860725
3  51.954168  5.866390
4  51.954889  5.868611
```

-

**Do your job to `df` here.**

-

Then finally arrange back dataframe `t` to the original dataframe `df`.

```
df = df.append(t).sort_index()
df
    lat        lon        name
0  51.954974  5.857131   Metamorfosenallee
1  51.955014  5.860725   Burgemeester Matsersingel
2  NaN        NaN        NaN
3  51.954168  5.866390   Burgemeester Matsersingel
4  51.954889  5.868611   Batavierenweg
```

Comment: Is it possible without the `df.dropna(inplace=True)`? I have other columns in the dataframe (I've updated the MWE) that I don't want to lose.

Comment: Wait -- `t` remembers the dropped rows *and their places* so the data is added back at the end! Right?!

Comment: but you don't use those other columns in the process of getting the `name` column, right? all rows that are containing `NaN` either in `lat ` on `lon` will be stored for awhile in `t`. So you won't lose it

Comment: correct -- I thought the `dropna` would cause data loss but in this answer it doesn't. Perfect!

Comment: I'm making a note here -- huge success!

Comment: I'm getting `FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned.  A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default. To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=True'. To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass sort=False` on the `df.append(t).sort_index()`. Which option should I pick?

Comment: Up to you. If you want to sort columns, `sort=True`. Your current version of pandas sorts it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Apply

```
df.lat.replace(np.nan, '', inplace=True)
df.lon.replace(np.nan, '', inplace=True)
```

to de function

Comment: That would replace all `np.nan`s with an empty string? That wouldn't help I think as OSRM also will not accept empty strings, and I want to retain the `np.nan`s in the dataframe.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `path` is 3 different things in the question.

Comment: Genera  ID. Then you filter the different to nan, make a join